# Is is possible create/delete/disable multiple breskpoints once in GDB?

Tags: configuration, gdb, breakpoints

I really like to `create/delete/disable` (and all other actions to breakpoint) multiple breakpoints in just one command line, such as:

```
b 12 28 30
```

to create 3 breakpoints at line 12, 28 and 30.

I googled many times, but got nothing.

Comment: It looks this can be done through MI interface (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Breakpoint-Commands.html#GDB_002fMI-Breakpoint-Commands). Can not not  ask: why/how is this different from multiple separate commands?

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in way to create multiple breakpoints with a single command is `rbreak`, but this isn't applicable to you, as it doesn't allow line numbers.

If you really need this for some reason, you can write a new command to do it.  You might be able to do this from the CLI using `define`, but, if not, you can easily use Python to write new commands.

Many other breakpoint commands like `enable` (but not all commands -- I think, e.g., not `cond` for syntax reasons) take a list of breakpoints to work on.